# Joomla Template - How can I auto hide a sidebar when there's no module?

Tags: templates, joomla, sidebar

I'm creating a new template in Joomla 3.0 and i'm having a problem with the sidebar. I want configure a flexible sidebar, like the one in the Prostar template and other, with the flexibility to hide when there's no module in the sidebar.

You can see what i mean in the example below. 
Image 1

[image: with-modules]

Image 2

[image: no-modules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the countModules() function in your index.php. If there are no modules hide the column and show a wider container, e.g.

```
<?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
    <div id="divLeft">show some stuff</div>
    <div id="divContent">show some stuff</div>
<?php else; ?>
    <div id="divContentWide">show a wider version of the content area</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Have divLeft and divContent 25% and 75% and have divContentWide 100%

Also have a look at the Beez3 template in your install to see another use of countModules